# GWT BrowserEvent, Internet Explorer, and dynamically applied inline style on Input or Select

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, input, event-handling, styles

I'm using GWT 2.5.0.

I've impl'd a custom abstract base widget for client-side validation feedback.  My question is related to dynamic inline styling of `<select/>` and `<input type="text"/>` widgets, particularly in Internet Explorer.

I cannot get the render to do its job properly and consistently on Internet Explorer 8/9.  For other browsers, like Safari, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, my impl functions just the way I want it to.

Basically, for pending, valid input, I want the background of the aforementioned widgets to be yellow, and the foreground color (text) to be blue.

I am using Tips and Tricks mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9.

I think the basic problem is that I'm running afoul of IE not supporting "event bubbling".
See ["Change" browser event in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452172/change-browser-event-in-gwt).  But I do not know how to address it.

**UPDATE**

It appears my implementation may be held hostage until

```
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7139
```

is fixed.

Here's my base abstract class. Note the user agent "hack" for Internet Explorer in the `onBrowserEvent` and `render` methods. (If there's some other way, please let me know).

```
public abstract class AbstractValidatableInputCell<E extends Element> extends AbstractInputCell<String, ValidationData> {

/**
 * The error message text, pop-up, callback, and position offsets -- error message will be displayed near a field that violated constraint.
 */
private String errorMessage;

private DecoratedPopupPanel errorMessagePopup;
private PopupPanel.PositionCallback popupPositionCallback;
private int popupPositionLeft;
private int popupPositionTop;


/**
 * Constructs a ValidatableInputCell that renders its text without HTML
 * markup.
 */
public AbstractValidatableInputCell(String... consumedEvents) {
    super(consumedEvents);
}


public void setErrorMessage(final String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant(errorMessage).asString();
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(final Context context, final Element parent, final String value,
        final NativeEvent event, final ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);

    // Ignore events that don't target the input.
    final E input = getInputElement(parent);
    final Element target = event.getEventTarget().cast();
    if (!input.isOrHasChild(target)) {
        return;
    }

    final String eventType = event.getType();
    final Object key = context.getKey();
    ValidationData vd = getViewData(key);
    final boolean invalid = vd == null ? false : vd.isInvalid();


    if (BrowserEvents.CHANGE.equals(eventType)) {
        finishEditing(parent, value, key, valueUpdater);

    } else if (Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().contains("MSIE")
            && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_TAB)) { 
        finishEditing(parent, value, key, valueUpdater);
        getInputElement(parent).focus();

    } else if (BrowserEvents.KEYUP.equals(eventType)) {
        // Record keys as they are typed.
        if (vd == null) {
            vd = new ValidationData(value);
            setViewData(key, vd);
        }
        vd.setCurrentValue(getValue(input));

    } else if (BrowserEvents.MOUSEOVER.equals(eventType)) {
        if (invalid) {
            showErrorMessagePopup(parent);
        }

    } else if (BrowserEvents.MOUSEOUT.equals(eventType)) {
        if (invalid) {
            hideErrorMessagePopup();
        }
    }
}

protected void onFinishEditing(final String value, final E input, final Object key) {
    /*
     * If viewData is null, just paint the contents black. If it is non-null,
     * show the pending value and paint the contents red if they are known to
     * be invalid.
     */
    final ValidationData viewData = getViewData(key);
    final String pendingValue = viewData == null ? null : viewData.getCurrentValue();
    final boolean invalid = viewData == null ? false : viewData.isInvalid();

    String color;
    String backgroundColor;

    if (invalid) {
        color = App.INSTANCE.invalidCellInputTextColor();
        backgroundColor = App.INSTANCE.invalidCellInputTextBackgroundColor();
    } else if (pendingValue != null && !pendingValue.equals(value)) {
        color = App.INSTANCE.pendingCellInputTextColor();
        backgroundColor = App.INSTANCE.pendingCellInputTextBackgroundColor();
    } else {
        color = App.INSTANCE.defaultCellInputTextColor();
        backgroundColor = App.INSTANCE.defaultCellInputTextBackgroundColor();
    }

    // Mark cell as containing a pending change
    input.getStyle().setColor(color);
    input.getStyle().setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
}

private void showErrorMessagePopup(final Element parent) {
    errorMessagePopup = new DecoratedPopupPanel(true);
    final FlowPanel messageContainer = new FlowPanel();
    messageContainer.setWidth(App.INSTANCE.errorMessagePopupWidth());
    final Label messageTxt = new Label(errorMessage, true);
    messageTxt.setStyleName(UiResources.INSTANCE.style().error());
    messageContainer.add(messageTxt);
    errorMessagePopup.setWidget(messageContainer);

    final Node child = parent.getChild(0);
    final Element childElement = (Element) child;

    // Reposition the popup relative to input field
    popupPositionLeft = childElement.getAbsoluteLeft() - 15;
    popupPositionTop = childElement.getAbsoluteBottom() + 5;

    popupPositionCallback = new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {

        @Override
        public void setPosition(final int offsetWidth, final int offsetHeight) {
            errorMessagePopup.setPopupPosition(popupPositionLeft, popupPositionTop);
        }
    };
    errorMessagePopup.setPopupPositionAndShow(popupPositionCallback);
}

private void hideErrorMessagePopup() {
    errorMessagePopup.hide();
}

@Override
public void render(final Context context, final String value, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    // Get the view data.
    final Object key = context.getKey();
    final ValidationData viewData = getViewData(key);

    final String pendingValue = viewData == null ? null : viewData.getCurrentValue();
    final boolean invalid = viewData == null ? false : viewData.isInvalid();

    String inputValue = value;
    if (pendingValue != null) {
        inputValue = pendingValue;
    }

    String color;
    String backgroundColor;

    if (invalid) {
        color = App.INSTANCE.invalidCellInputTextColor();
        backgroundColor = App.INSTANCE.invalidCellInputTextBackgroundColor();
    } else if (pendingValue != null) {
        color = App.INSTANCE.pendingCellInputTextColor();
        backgroundColor = App.INSTANCE.pendingCellInputTextBackgroundColor();
    } else {
        color = App.INSTANCE.defaultCellInputTextColor();
        backgroundColor = App.INSTANCE.defaultCellInputTextBackgroundColor();
    }

    // shame on you IE!
    if (Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().contains("MSIE") && viewData != null && !viewData.isPended() && !invalid) {
        color = App.INSTANCE.defaultCellInputTextColor();
        backgroundColor = App.INSTANCE.defaultCellInputTextBackgroundColor();
    }

    finishRender(inputValue, color, backgroundColor, sb);
}

protected abstract void finishRender(final String inputValue, final String color, final String backgroundColor, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb);

@Override
protected void finishEditing(final Element parent, final String value, final Object key,
        final ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    final String newValue = getNewValue(parent);

    // Get the view data.
    ValidationData vd = getViewData(key);
    if (vd == null) {
        vd = new ValidationData(value);
        setViewData(key, vd);
    }
    vd.setCurrentValue(newValue);

    // Fire the value updater if the value has changed.
    if (valueUpdater != null && !vd.getCurrentValue().equals(vd.getLastValue())) {
        vd.setLastValue(newValue);
        valueUpdater.update(newValue);
    }

    onFinishEditing(value, getInputElement(parent), key);

    // Blur the element.
    super.finishEditing(parent, newValue, key, valueUpdater);
}

@Override
protected E getInputElement(final Element parent) {
    return super.getInputElement(parent).<E> cast();
}

protected abstract String getValue(E element);

protected abstract String getNewValue(Element parent);
}
```

Here's a sample sub-class (for `input`):

```
public class ValidatableInputCell extends AbstractValidatableInputCell<InputElement> {

interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {

    @Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" size=\"{1}\" style=\"color: {2}; background-color: {3}; display: block; text-align: right\"></input>")
    SafeHtml input(String value, String width, String color, String backgroundColor);
}

private static Template template;

private static final int DEFAULT_INPUT_SIZE = App.INSTANCE.defaultValidatableInputCellSize();

/**
 * Specifies the width, in characters, of the &lt;input&gt; element contained within this cell
 */
private int inputSize = DEFAULT_INPUT_SIZE;

/**
 * Constructs a ValidatableInputCell that renders its text without HTML
 * markup.
 */
public ValidatableInputCell() {
    // Since onBrowserEvent method is overridden, we must register all
    // events that handled in overridden method impl
    // Events below are added in
    // AbstractInputCell#getConsumedEventsImpl(Set<String> userEvents)
    super(BrowserEvents.CHANGE, BrowserEvents.KEYUP, BrowserEvents.MOUSEOVER, BrowserEvents.MOUSEOUT);
    if (template == null) {
        template = GWT.create(Template.class);
    }
}

public void setInputSize(final int inputSize) {
    this.inputSize = inputSize;
}


@Override
public void finishRender(final String inputValue, final String color, final String backgroundColor, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    sb.append(template.input(inputValue, String.valueOf(inputSize), color, backgroundColor));
}

@Override
protected String getValue(InputElement element) {
    return element.getValue();
}

@Override
protected String getNewValue(Element parent) {
    return getValue(getInputElement(parent));
}


}
```

Here's another sample sub-class (for `select`):

```
public class ReferenceDataBackedSelectionCell extends AbstractValidatableInputCell<SelectElement> {

interface SelectTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<select style=\"color: {0}; background-color: {1};\">")
    SafeHtml select(String color, String backgroundColor);
}

interface OptionTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {

    @Template("<option style=\"color: {2}; background-color: {3}; text-align: right\" value=\"{0}\">{1}</option>")
    SafeHtml deselected(String optionSubmitValue, String optionDisplayValue, String color, String backgroundColor);

    @Template("<option style=\"color: {2}; background-color: {3}; text-align: right\" value=\"{0}\" selected=\"selected\">{1}</option>")
    SafeHtml selected(String optionSubmitValue, String optionDisplayValue, String color, String backgroundColor);
}

private static SelectTemplate selectTemplate; 
private static OptionTemplate optionTemplate;

private final Map<String, String> options;

/**
 * Construct a new {@link ReferenceDataBackedSelectionCell} from
 * {@link ReferenceData}.
 * 
 * @param refData data used to create the options in the cell
 */
public ReferenceDataBackedSelectionCell(final ReferenceData refData) {
    super(BrowserEvents.CHANGE);
    if (optionTemplate == null) {
        optionTemplate = GWT.create(OptionTemplate.class);
    }
    if (selectTemplate == null) {
        selectTemplate = GWT.create(SelectTemplate.class);
    }
    if (refData == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Reference data for selection cell may not be null");
    }
    options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(refData.allData());
}

@Override
public void finishRender(final String inputValue, final String color, final String backgroundColor, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    final String selectedIndex = inputValue == null ? "" : inputValue;
    sb.append(selectTemplate.select(color, backgroundColor));
    String optionSubmitValue, optionDisplayValue = null;
    for (final Map.Entry<String, String> option : options.entrySet()) {
        optionSubmitValue = option.getValue();
        optionDisplayValue = option.getKey();
        if (optionSubmitValue.equals(selectedIndex)) {
            sb.append(optionTemplate.selected(optionSubmitValue, optionDisplayValue, color, backgroundColor));
        } else {
            sb.append(optionTemplate.deselected(optionSubmitValue, optionDisplayValue, color, backgroundColor));
        }
    }
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("</select>");
}

@Override
protected String getValue(SelectElement element) {
    return element.getValue();
}

@Override
protected String getNewValue(Element parent) {
    final SelectElement select = parent.getFirstChild().cast();
    final Collection<String> optionCollection = options.values();
    final String[] array = optionCollection.toArray(new String[optionCollection.size()]);
    final String newValue = array[select.getSelectedIndex()];
    return newValue;
}
}
```

Comment: Just a thought - CSS3 with default/onfocus style change without gwt code might do this.

Comment: That might be an option with a library like http://selectivizr.com/.  I may have been sleeping under a rock for the past 3 years, but I'm not entirely familiar with CSS3.

Another thought I had was to swap out a `class` rather than (re)setting attributes within a `style`.  I think I'm going to try that first, and report back.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Answer (score 0):

**I would try out CSS3 as IE9 has good support for it.**

### teststyle.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

INPUT[type="text"]:focus,
INPUT[type="number"]:focus,
INPUT[type="email"]:focus,
INPUT[type="search"]:focus,
INPUT[type="password"]:focus,
INPUT[type="range"]:focus
{
    outline: 1px solid #0033dd;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;   
}
```

### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teststyle.css" />
</head>

<body>
 <input name="" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

### IE9 screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'll try for IE9, but I also need something that works for IE8. Is there something like a shim that will backport CSS3 capabilities into IE8 or earlier?

Comment: The above might work for ie8 ( i have not bothered to check). DEATH to IE*

Comment: The above recommendation didn't work for IE 9!  Still the same issue persists.

Comment: I will try this out again and delete the answer if it does not work on a test box.

Comment: Updated answer. I have assumed you need to highlight border of textbox on focus to blue, set the background to grey and font color white. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Styling is not the real problem. GWT DataGrid support for Cell based browserEvents is the problem. I can statically style an input and select control. The challenge is triggering that style for IE on blur.

Comment: The above styles are applied when you click into text box and removed when the textbox loose focus.

Comment: Not the desired behavior. What we need is to show pending updates. That means if the original value was updated, then the style is applied (onchange, onselect, onblur). The solution you recommend is only a highlighting option when control has focus.

Comment: Okay. Is there any way i can keep the answer and still avoid bonus points?

Comment: Note. You will not get the points back to your account if i delete the answer. I do not wish to have the bonus points but i would mind deleting the answer as i went a bit out of my way to write the sample. Can you not post your own answer and accept it there by cancelling the bonus points.

Comment: I'm greatful you took the time to respond. I know it takes time to answer difficult questions thoughtfully. I just wish Stackoverflow had some more human monitoring on bounties. I'm not much of an expert so building up reputation an then expending what little I have on a bounty to get a proposed answer that, while related, does not solve my particular problem is what I'm peeved about.